# PLSQL - wrong type or number of parameters

Tags: oracle, plsql

we have a procedure in Oracle/PLSQL. it works fine when tested independently but when we call it through C# it raises the error that the parameter count/type is wrong.

```
Command.CommandText = "Store Procedure";
            Command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            Command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("P_DATE", OracleDbType.Date, model.END_DATE, ParameterDirection.Input));
            Command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("P_MAIN_ENTITY_ID", OracleDbType.Int64, model.MainEntityID, ParameterDirection.Input));

            Command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("P_INDEX_PAGE", OracleDbType.Int32, frmRow, ParameterDirection.Input));
            Command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("p_pageSize", OracleDbType.Int32, model.toRow, ParameterDirection.Input));

            Command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("P_ENTITY_ID", OracleDbType.Int32, model.EntityID, ParameterDirection.Input));
            Command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("P_PARAMETERS_JSON", OracleDbType.Varchar2, getJsonString(Command), ParameterDirection.Input));
           
            Command.Parameters.AddOpLogParamVarChar(opLog.ToString());
            Command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("P_TRANS_LIST_C", OracleDbType.RefCursor, ParameterDirection.Output));
```

the procedure definition is as under:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ABC(
                     P_INDEX_PAGE IN integer,
                      p_pageSize IN integer,
                      P_DATE               IN DATE,
                      P_MAIN_ENTITY_ID     IN ENTITY.ENTITY_ID%TYPE,
                      P_ENTITY_ID          IN ENTITY.ENTITY_ID%TYPE,
                      P_PARAMETERS_JSON    IN PARAMETER_LOG.PARAMETER_JSON%TYPE,
                      P_OP_LOG             IN OUT VARCHAR2,
                      P_TRANS_LIST_C       OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) IS
```

funny thing is that when we comment index size and page size, it works fine. but using either, it raises the error.

any help appreciated.

Comment: read this article, it might help you. https://oradim.blogspot.com/2009/08/odpnet-vb-and-from-type-to-type-is-not.html

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the values ​​passed in the variables model.toRow or frmRow are too large for the pl / sql INTEGER type.
The simplest solution would be to change the P_INDEX_PAGE and p_pageSize types to NUMBER.

Comment: thanks for answer but the issue was in sequence in C# code.